# Generic-inherited classes storing their parent ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, binding, observablecollection

I have several collections, each of specific class. I need that every instance (model) store its parent collection (to be able to reach other instances because of data validation). Trying to find some smart solution - starting to doubt if there is such.

So far I came up with following.

Generic base-class:

```
public class ModelBase<T> : ObservableObject, IDataErrorInfo
{
    public CustomObservableCollection<T> ParentCollection;

    public int Id { get; set; }  // some generic prop
}
```

Individual classes (models):

```
public class Model1: ModelBase<Model1>
{
    public string Name { get; set; } // Some specific prop

    // Data Error validation here, e.g. check of uniqueness
    if (ParentCollection?.Where(c => c.Id != Id).Any(c => c.Name == Name) == true)
    {
    }

}

public class Model2: ModelBase<Model2>
{}
```

Custom ObservableCollection:

```
public class CustomObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T> where T : ModelBase<T>
{
    public CustomObservableCollection() : base() { }

    public CustomObservableCollection(List<T> list)
            : base(list)
    {
        foreach (T item in list)
        {
            item.ParentCollection = this;
        }
    }

    public void AddEdit(T item)
    {
        item.ParentCollection = this;

        base.Add(item);
    }

    protected override void InsertItem(int index, T item)
    {
        base.InsertItem(index, item);

        item.ParentCollection = this;

        // Initialize values
    }

    // Generic method - I would like to call this directly from command handler regardless of type T
    public void MoveItemUp(object parameter) 
    {

    }

}
```

Usage:

```
CustomObservableCollection<Model1> Model1Collection = new (listOfModel1instances);
```

I've been also trying to use Interfaces, but without success.

**EDIT 1**

I need to add some information I forget to mention in the beginning.

In my CustomObservableCollection class I would like to have some generic methods processing collection belonging to Item given by argument, e.g.

```
public int GetMaxId(t item)
{
     return item.Source.Max(i => i.Id);
}
```

What I get:
Error   CS1061  'ICollection' does not contain a definition for 'Max' ...

(Given example does not give much sense. But let's assume, that all items have Order property. In command handler I want to reorder items in collection, e.g. move selected item up/down. In command handler all I have is just selected item given by command parameter. 
This would allow me to have just one Command for all types of items.)

Comment: If I understand your problem properly, You need to create another class for validation like `ObservableCollection<CustomObservableCollection<T>> where T : ModelBase<T>`. The other question about interface, in my opinion is that you should analyze whether you need `interface` or an `abstract class`.

Comment: If each object scans the parent collection, you have a `O(n^2)` performance problem. Instead you should validate the collection, with a `HashSet` lazily added to the `ValidationContext`. Each object should add their `.Name` to the collection, failing validation if it already exists.

Answer (score 0):

Your question (with the additional information you provided) indicates that the items in your collection require access to the parent collection and must provide an `Id` property, for example so that the parent collection can use the linq `Max` method.

[image: console output]

One way to solve both objectives is to define an interface like `ISourceAware` and constrain `CustomObservableCollection<T>` to accept only items that implement it by adding `where T: ISourceAware` to its declaration.

```
public interface ISourceAware
{
    ICollection Source { get; set; }
    int Id { get; }
}
public class CustomObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T> where T: ISourceAware
{
    protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnCollectionChanged(e);
        if(e.Action.Equals(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)) 
        {
            foreach (ISourceAware iitem in e.NewItems)
            {
                iitem.Source = this;
#if DEBUG
                var item = (Item)iitem;
                // Try a loopback test
                Console.WriteLine(
                    $"Index of {item.Description} is {item.ParentCollection.IndexOf(item)}");
#endif
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The collection handles its own `CollectionChanged` notification to set itself as the `Source` of any item added to it. This addresses the primary issue of **storing their parent ObservableCollection** - you can use it for validation however you see fit.

---

A minimal example of a class that implements `ISourceAware`:

```
public class Item : ISourceAware
{
    public string Description { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public ICollection Source { get; set; }
    public CustomObservableCollection<Item> ParentCollection =>
        (CustomObservableCollection<Item>)Source;
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

---

**Test**

Here's the quick console code I wrote to test this answer.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Title = "Test ISourceAware";
    var collection = new CustomObservableCollection<Item>();

    collection.Add(new Item { Description = "Item 1", Id = 1 });
    collection.Add(new Item { Description = "Item 2", Id = 2 });

    Console.WriteLine($"Min: {collection.Min(_ => _.Id)}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Max: {collection.Max(_ => _.Id)}");

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

---

**Response to question edit**

You posted:

> In my CustomObservableCollection class I would like to have some generic methods processing collection belonging to Item given by argument, e.g.

```
public int GetMaxId(t item)
{
     return item.Source.Max(i => i.Id);
}
```

---

Often when you have an `interface` type you will want to cast it to its underlying type. Here's an example of a decent way to go about doing that.

```
public class CustomObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T> where T: ISourceAware
{
    .
    .
    . 
    public static int GetMaxId(T item)
    {
        if (item.Source is ObservableCollection<T> items)
        {
            return items.Max(i => i.Id);
        }
        else throw new ArgumentException("Source must be an ObservableCollection<T>");
    }
}
```

But because the signature of the `Max` extension takes `IEnumerable<T>` it would be better to do it this way, which would accept `List<T>` and `T[]` in addition to `ObservableCollection<T>`.

```
public class CustomObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T> where T: ISourceAware
{
    .
    .
    . 
    public static int GetMaxId(T item)
    {
        if (item.Source is IEnumerable<T> items)
        {
            return items.Max(i => i.Id);
        }
        else throw new ArgumentException("Source must be an IEnumerable<T> collection");
    }
}
```

---

That said, the only way that the method you posted makes any sense if there's a possibility that the `item` being passed in might belong to a *different* collection. If that's not the case then there's no need for an argument at all.

```
public class CustomObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T> where T: ISourceAware
{
    .
    .
    . 
    public int GetMaxId()
    {
        return this.Max(i => i.Id);
    }
}
```

Regardless of how you choose to implement `GetMaxId()` in your custom observable class, it doesn't change anything about my previous answer.

Comment: Thank you for useful reaction, IVSoftware.
I've tried to implement it according your example, but I ran into other issue I forget to mention in the beginning - I have edited my original question.

Comment: Thank you for update, IVSoftware. Still I don't see any way how to access all IDs from parameter given to method in CustomObservableCollection. I cannot call item.Source.Max(i => i.iD). And as this argument (item) is of type T where T : ISourceAware i do not have access to ParentCollection property.

Comment: My mistake. The `Id` property has been `int` all along and I missed that. My answer now stands corrected.